# Trying to make macro similar to defparameter, defvar but macro only returns an s-expression

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I'm trying to make macros for defining various object similar to `defparameter` and `defvar`. The `defregion1` macro works: upon executing it defines a variable with object `region`. However, `defregion2` only returns an expression that must be executed manually. Here is the code:

```
(defclass location ()
  ((x
    :initarg :x
    :accessor x)
   (y
    :initarg :y
    :accessor y)))

(defclass region ()
  ((x :initarg :x
      :accessor x)
   (y :initarg :y
      :accessor y)
   (w :initarg :w
      :accessor w)
   (h :initarg :h
      :accessor h)))

(defmacro deflocation (var x y)
  `(defparameter ,var `(make-instance 'location :x ,x :y ,y)))


(defmacro defregion1 (var x y w h)
  `(defparameter ,(intern (symbol-name var))
       (make-instance 'region :x ,x :y ,y :w ,w :h ,h)))

(defmacro defregion2 (var l1 l2)
  `(with-slots ((x1 x) (y1 y))
       ,l1
     (with-slots ((x2 x) (y2 y))
         ,l2
       `(defparameter ,(intern (symbol-name ,var))
           (make-instance 'region
                          :x ,x1 :y ,y1 :w (- ,x2 ,x1) :h (- ,y2 ,y1))))))
```

The output of `defregion1`:

```
(defregion1 *test-reg1* 1 2 3 4) 

=> *test-reg1*
```

The output of `deferegion2`:

```
(deflocation *l1* 20 30)
(deflocation *l2* 50 60)
(defregion2 '*test-reg2* *l1* *l2*)

=> (DEFPARAMETER *TEST-REG2*
     (MAKE-INSTANCE 'REGION :X 20 :Y 30 :W (- 50 20) :H (- 60 30)))
```

I want `*test-reg2*` to also become a variable. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two nested backquotes.

But your macro is also inside-out: you really want `defparameter` at the top-level, so something like this would be better:

```
(defmacro defregion2 (var l1 l2)
  `(defparameter ,(intern (symbol-name ,var)) 
     (with-slots ((x1 x) (y1 y))
         ,l1
       (with-slots ((x2 x) (y2 y))
           ,l2
         (make-instance 'region :x x1 :y y1 :w (- x2 x1) :h (- y2 y1))))))
```

Also are you *sure* you want this slightly odd internery?  What that's going to do is take the name of the symbol you give as an argument and intern it in the current package.  So for instance

```
(defregion2 x:*foo* ...)
```

will result in a symbol `*foo*` in the current package, instead of giving a value to `x:*foo*`.  (Of course this all collapses into the same thing if the current package *is* `x`).

I suspect you possibly want

```
(defmacro defregion2 (var l1 l2)
  `(defparameter ,var
     (with-slots ((x1 x) (y1 y))
         ,l1
       (with-slots ((x2 x) (y2 y))
           ,l2
         (make-instance 'region :x x1 :y y1 :w (- x2 x1) :h (- y2 y1))))))
```

Your code is also potentially unhygenic as it binds variables (really symbol macros) with names which are visible to whatever `l2` is: it would be safer as

```
(defmacro defregion2 (var l1 l2)
  `(defparameter ,var
     (let ((l1 ,l1) (l2 ,l2))
       (with-slots ((x1 x) (y1 y))
           l1
         (with-slots ((x2 x) (y2 y))
             l2
           (make-instance 'region :x x1 :y y1 :w (- x2 x1) :h (- y2 y1)))))))
```

This is now safe as you can see from the expansion:

```
(defregion2 *thing* 
            (expression-involving x1 x2)
            (another-expression-involving x1 x2))
```

expands to

```
(defparameter *thing*
  (let ((l1 (expression-involving x1 x2))
        (l2 (another-expression-involving x1 x2)))
    (with-slots ((x1 x) (x2 y)) l1
      (with-slots ((x2 x) (y2 y)) l2
        (make-instance 'region :x x1 :y y1 :w (- x2 x1) :h (- y2 y1))))))
```

You can see that the `x1` in `(another-expression-involving x1 ...)` is not the one that is bound by `with-slots`.

Comment: Thank you. As for the `intern`, it kept evaluating to unbound variable so I tried to fix it. But this seems to be the problem of nested backquotes.